# Array initialisation inside class's private members in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, queue

In my following implementation of a circular queue, I did not initialize `array` by myself and the code ran fine but my IDE gave me a suggestion to add {} just after declaration & definition of `int arr[MAX]` and it now looked like `int arr[MAX] {}`. I want to know what is the difference between these two? I could initialize the `array` elements to 0 by `int arr[MAX] = {0};`. Are `int arr[MAX]{}` and `int arr[MAX] = {0}` same?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 8

template <class T>
class Queue {
private:
    int front, rear;
    T arr[MAX]{}; //This line over here
public:
    Queue(){
        front = rear = -1;
    }
    bool empty();
    bool full();
    void push(T);
    void pop();
    void print();
};

template <typename T>
bool Queue<T>:: empty() {
    return front == -1 && rear == -1;
}

template <typename T>
bool Queue<T>:: full() {
    return (rear + 1) % MAX == front;
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>:: push(T data) {
    if(full())
        cout << "Overflow" << endl;

    else {
        if(empty())
            front = rear = 0;
        else {
            rear = (rear + 1) % MAX;
        }
        arr[rear] = data;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>:: pop() {
    if(empty())
        cout << "Underflow" << endl;
    else {
        if(front == rear)
            front = rear = -1;
        else {
            front = (front + 1) % MAX;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>:: print() {
    if(!empty()) {
        int count = (rear + (MAX - front)) % MAX + 1;
        for(auto i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            int index = (front + i) % MAX;
            cout << arr[index] << " ";
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    Queue<int> qu;
    qu.push(4);
    qu.push(34);
    qu.push(324);
    qu.push(314);
    qu.push(47);
    qu.push(64);
    qu.pop();
    qu.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`T arr[MAX]{}` will call default constructor for each array element, and for T equal to `int` it will set all values to zero. On the other hand, `int arr[MAX] = {0}` will create an array of size `MAX` and then set only the first element to zero.

Comment: "...set only the first element to zero". No! If you partially initialise an array in C/C++ the remaining elements are set to 0 (this is not the case if you don't initialise at all). https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization